# How to convert Text values to number values in Excel 2003 (Number stored as Text), using C#

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2003

There appear to be a number of suggestions to do this, non of which appear to work.

Effectively, I'm wanting to change a text value in an Excel sheet to a number (this is a cell that has been set as a number stored as text, and has a green diamond next to it).

This [webpage](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/02/18/number-stored-as-text/) details how to resolve the issue in Excel, through the UI, and I've recorded this as a macro below (but that's VBA)...

Including setting the value to itself:

```
                Range allCellsRng;
                string lowerRightCell = "AZ500";
                allCellsRng = wSheet.get_Range("A1", lowerRightCell).Cells;
                foreach (Range cell in allCellsRng)
                {
                    if (cell.Value2.ToString().Length > 0)
                    {
                        cell.Value2 = cell.Value2;
                    }
                }
```

This is a recorded VB Macro, that shows what will resolve the issue, but I'm having problems representing this in C#:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so raising it as a question on here triggered a brainwave. This looks to work:

```
Range cellA1 = wSheet.get_Range("A1", System.Type.Missing);
cellA1.Value2 = "0";
cellA1.Copy(System.Type.Missing);
Range cellAll = wSheet.get_Range("A1:AZ500", System.Type.Missing);
cellAll.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd,
        false, false);
```

Comment: If the macro works, then that will work, as it's exactly the same as the macro...

Comment: This code works only when you set first cell value to 0 as you did, however in any other case it will just add it up, producing incorrect results

Answer (score 1):

With Clear Office, the code is very easy:

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName);
foreach (Worksheet worksheet in spreadsheetDocument.Workbook.Sheets.OfType<Worksheet>())
{
    foreach (Cell cell in worksheet.GetRange("A1:AZ500"))
    {
        string s = cell.Value as string;
        if (s == null)
            continue;
        double d;
        if (double.TryParse(s, out d))
            cell.Value = d;
        }
    }
spreadsheetDocument.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to change the format of the cell instead? I believe you should be able to grab the format using

```
range.NumberFormat
```

and change that to the actual format you want... You could then set the range for an entire column, or whole sheet.

Comment: The cell is already formatted as a number, it's just that Excel is storing the number as text. As per the webpage link, if you press F2 and enter (basically open the cell, and exit it) the number is stored as a number.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a particular NumberFormat that says store as text, or prefixing the value with a ' does the same thing.

Comment: Otherwise why don't you use the Range.PasteSpecial() method?